# How to use adapter in an ember-engines

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-engines

as the title says, I have some problems understanding how to use an adapter in an ember-engines.
I am currently running my application with `ember@2.15`, `ember-data@2.15` and `ember-engines@0.5.14`. 
I already used an adapter in my main application, but if I tried to reproduce a basic adapter in my application, the page is loading indefinitely.
In my route, I call my adapter with the `findAll` method:

```
  model()
    {
        "use strict";
         console.log('In my route');
         return this.get('store').findAll('my-adapter-name', {reload: true});
    }
```

And in my adapter, I respect the syntax that I used in my in-app adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Adapter.extend({

    findAll: function (store, type, sinceToken, snapshotRecordArray)
    {
        console.log("In my adapter");
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject)
        {
        // I accede to my websocket service here, nothing to do with my question
        });
    },
    /* *
    * My other function, like findRecord, ect...
    */
});
```

As you can see, I put some `console.log` in my code, and I can access the message in my route, which is in my engine, but I can't access the message in my adapter, which is also in my engine.
I tried to put a `console.log` in an adapter in my application, and the message is properly shown, so I am sure this is because I can't access to the adapter in my engine, so if anybody has an idea to how we should configure our adapter in our `ember-engines`, this would be very appreciated.
For your information, this is an `in-repo` engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it, this is a bit tricky, but your `models` (and `adapters`) should be in the `myApp/lib/myEngine/app/models/`, and not in `myApp/lib/myEngine/addon/models`.

I don't know if this is intended this way, but this is the only way I found to add model in your *in-repo* **ember-engines**.

---

**EDIT**
This will do the trick for the `serializers` and the `transform`.